# Property database query - userFunction is not found

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am trying to follow [these instructions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/tutorials/propdb-queries/) to query the property database of a model. Everything works fine when testing on a local development server, but when I deploy it to firebase I get this error:

`Uncaught (in promise) {msg: "function 'userFunction' was not found."}`

Below is my code:

```
const viewerHelperPlugin = {
install(Vue){
Vue.prototype.$viewerHelper = {
  getElementsByPropertyValue: function (viewer, propertyName, propertyValue, operator) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      function userFunction (pdb, userData) {
        var attrIndex = -1;
        // Iterate over all attributes and find the index to the one we are interested in
        pdb.enumAttributes(function(i, attrDef, attrRaw){
          var name = attrDef.name;
          if (name === userData.propertyName) {
              attrIndex = i;
              return true; // to stop iterating over the remaining attributes.
          }
        });
        // Early return is the model doesn't contain data.
        if (attrIndex === -1)
          return [];

        var returnElements = [];

        pdb.enumObjects(function(dbId) {
          // For each part, iterate over their properties.
          pdb.enumObjectProperties(dbId, function(attrId, valId){
            if (attrId === attrIndex) {
              var value = pdb.getAttrValue(attrId, valId);
              if (userData.operator === "==" && value === userData.propertyValue) {
                  returnElements.push(dbId);
              }
              else if (userData.operator === ">" && value > userData.propertyValue) {
                returnElements.push(dbId);
              }
              else if (userData.operator === ">=" && value >= userData.propertyValue) {
                returnElements.push(dbId);
              }
              else if (userData.operator === "<" && value < userData.propertyValue) {
                returnElements.push(dbId);
              }
              else if (userData.operator === "<=" && value <= userData.propertyValue) {
                returnElements.push(dbId);
              }
              else if (userData.operator === "!=" && value != userData.propertyValue) {
                returnElements.push(dbId);
              }
            }
          });
        });
        return returnElements;
      }
      var thePromise = viewer.model.getPropertyDb().executeUserFunction( userFunction, 
{propertyName: propertyName, propertyValue: propertyValue, operator: operator } );
      thePromise.then(function(retValue){
        resolve(retValue);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

} 
}

I am not sure why it cannot find the function as I declare it immediately above the statement.

Comment: The userFunction would get passed to the worker as blob and looks like that process has somehow failed. When it fails it should reject the promise with an error message - try catch the reject and inspect the error with `thePromise.catch(err=>console.log(err))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. I am using Vue for my frontend, and when I pulled my function out of the Vue instance and into the global JavaScript scope it worked.

[Edit: why this works]
This problem typically occurs when you use a JavaScript module bundler like Vite or Webpack in your build process. Most frontend frameworks like React, Angular, and Vue use module bundlers.

Part of the bundling process involves minifying and code obfuscation, which results in renamed functions in the compiled code. Because the Forge library is looking specifically for a function named "userFunction", it can't find it because the function has been renamed.

It's an odd design choice to have a requirement like that, but the workaround is to ensure that the bundler does not rename that function, either by moving it outside of the bundling process or specifically excluding it in the bundler's compile options.

Comment: I am encountering the same issue at this moment, could you post your solution in detail?

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing function renaming issues while using the Quasar framework, here's the solution that has worked for me:

1. Make sure you have the terser-webpack-plugin installed as a dev dependency in your project:

   npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev

2.Update your quasar.conf.js to import the TerserPlugin at the beginning of the file:

```
// quasar.conf.js

const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin'); // Add this line to import TerserPlugin

module.exports = function (/* ctx */) {
  return {
    build: {
      // Configure Webpack optimization
      extendWebpack(cfg) {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
          // Create a new TerserPlugin instance with the desired options
          const newTerserPlugin = new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
              keep_fnames: true,
            },
          });

          // Replace the existing TerserPlugin instance with the new one
          cfg.optimization.minimizer = cfg.optimization.minimizer.map((minimizer) =>
            minimizer.constructor.name === 'TerserPlugin' ? newTerserPlugin : minimizer
          );
        }
      },
    },
    // ... other config options ...
  };
};
```